# How to interact with USSD dialog programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, ussd, sim-card, accessibilityservice

I want to use **USSD dialog** which comes after dialing any **USSD code** say ***123#** which asks user to enter option number to perform specific task(s) depending upon sim card vendors. I need to interact with that dialog to provide input in the text box given into it programmatically.

However, I am able to read the **USSD response** that comes in Alert Dialog after dialing any USSD code, using `AccessibilityService` and I'm showing the response in a `Toast` as shown in the code below. I haven't found any solution to interact with USSD dialog yet.

```
public class UssdService extends AccessibilityService{
    public static String TAG = "USSD";

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
        String text = event.getText().toString();
        if (event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) {
            Log.d(TAG, text);
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
        info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.android.phone"};
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }
}
```

Here is the service declaration in Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".UssdService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/config_service" />
</service>
```

Comment: If you want to set click event then use below code  List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Send");
                                    for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                                        node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                                        isDialogClose = true;
                                    }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For interacting with USSD dialog, I used below code.

I used the below code for click event:

```
List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Send");
for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
     node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
}
```

I used the below code for `setText` in `EditText`. This is `setText` where the current focus is.

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInput = nodeInfo.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_INPUT);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();        
bundle.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,pMPIN);
nodeInput.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT,bundle);
nodeInput.refresh();
```

Comment: How do I get nodeInfo?

Comment: I wish you gave a longer explanation. I don't know how to use your code though it points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

My company [Hover](https://www.usehover.com) has developed an Android SDK which uses accessibility services to run multi-step USSD sessions and have it appear to happen inside your app. The underlying method is similar to what is outlined in the accepted answer, but there is more of an abstraction layer, support for lots of devices that behave differently, and it hides the session from the user.

You create configurations for USSD services, trigger the session to run from your app and pass in any runtime variables you need. When the response is returned your app is notified and you can parse it as you need. It works on Android 4.3 and above.

The SDK is free to integrate and use until you hit large scale. Please see our [docs](https://docs.usehover.com) to get started.

(Disclosure: I am the CTO of Hover)